# Configuring Groovy MarkupTemplateEngine in Spring Boot leads to Cast Exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy

I am trying to configure a custom Template class for the `MarkupTemplateEngine` in Spring Boot, which allows writing templates in Groovy. My configuration is pretty simple:

```groovy
@Configuration
class TemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public GroovyMarkupConfig groovyMarkupConfigurer() {
        new GroovyMarkupConfigurer().tap {
            resourceLoaderPath = 'classpath:/templates/'
            baseTemplateClass = MainTemplate
        }
    }

}
```

When changing the `resourceLoaderPath` to a non-existent path I get an 404 error, which reveals, that that configuration is loaded properly. However, when using `setBaseTemplateClass(Class<? extends BaseTemplate>)` as in the snippet above, I get the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException:
    Cannot cast object 
    'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.groovy.GroovyMarkupConfigurer@111bb71a'
    with class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.groovy.GroovyMarkupConfigurer'
    to class 'TemplateConfiguration'
```

I have no clue, why this error comes up. My custom Template class looks like this:

```groovy
abstract class MainTemplate extends BaseTemplate {

    MainTemplate(MarkupTemplateEngine templateEngine, Map model, Map<String, String> modelTypes,
                 TemplateConfiguration configuration) {
        super(templateEngine, model, modelTypes, configuration)
    }

    void doctype() {
        yieldUnescaped '<!DOCTYPE html>'
    }
}
```

Comment: Show where you’re using GroovyMarkupConfigurer and TemplateConfiguration.

Comment: The code above is all I wrote. Spring Boot automagically applies these configurations as I understood. The methods defined in the `MainTemplate` should be available in the template files.

Answer (score 0):

Letting the Configuration extend `GroovyMarkupConfigurer` and overwriting the properties solved the issue:

```groovy
@Configuration
class TemplateConfiguration extends GroovyMarkupConfigurer {

    final String resourceLoaderPath = 'classpath:/templates/'
    final Class<? extends BaseTemplate> baseTemplateClass = MainTemplate

}
```